# php convert time() to date format on the fly for sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `while` statement to `echo` some data to the user from specific dates.
I have stored the dates in my data base in this format: `time()` I want to write my sql statement in this format to check only the date `date("m/d/y", some time)`. like so:

```
$page_visits_count = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `visits` WHERE date('m/d/y', `time`) = '$date' ");
```

This part ``` date('m/d/y', ``time``) ``` is obviously wrong, but how would I be able to fix this problem ?
Note: I tried adding one day (3600 * 24) to my time.  But that sometimes put me the middle of the next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're wanting to convert a UNIX timestamp (stored in DB column `time`) into a date format, then compare that date to the `$date` variable.

If that's true, [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) is what you're probalby after:

```
"SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `visits` WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`, '%m/%d/%Y') = '$date'");
```

You'll probably want to tweak the `%m/%d/%Y` part to match the format of your `$date` variable, see the `FROM_UNIXTIME` docs I linked to for a list on what formats are available.